# SQL where @parameter like null

Tags: sql

For example i have a [table] like this:

```
Code Name    
123  ABC
NULL CBD
231  EFG
```

I need to filter that [table] by [code]. I could use `select * from [table] where [code] like '%' + @parameter + '%'`. But this query is not good because:

I. If @parameter is assigned to null or @parameter is assigned to '', i dont get extracted rows with [code] null.

II. If i use query `select * from [table] where [code] like '%' + @parameter + '%' or [code] is null` i always get extracted rows with null valuable even if for example @parameter = '12'.

I need to be able to assign @parameter to some string - empty or not empty ant get [table] filtered.

Comment: What you need is two different queries with pure SQL. If you run your query form some other programming language, you can build your query in a dynamic way, but you need to tell us what language that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way. This query works:

```
declare @parameter nvarchar(max)

if @parameter is null 
set @parameter = ''

select [code] from (select coalesce([code],'') from [table]) abc where abc.[code] like '%' + @parameter + '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly, here is a SQL Server version (other flavours might  differ in the concatenation):

```
select * 
from mytable 
where code like '%' + @parameter + '%' 
or (code is null and @parameter is null)
```